# String.Format("", object) without formatting of the object

Tags: c#, string

We have an xml-nodes with `attribute-node format` as the example demonstrates below

```
<txt field="dateChanged" format="{0:MM/dd/yy}" /> => Datetime
<txt field="duration" format="{0:dd\.hh\:mm\:ss}" /> => Timespan
<txt field="cost" format="{0:0,0.0}" /> => double
```

We print those `txt`s on pdf with the correct format using

```
Canvas.Drawtext( ..... , String.Format(chldNode.Attributes["format"].Value;,data));
```

I would like to use the same logic (and make the whole solution fully generic) to print standard text:

```
<txt field="Description" format="???"> This the productdescription </Description>
```

**What value must `???` to get the correct output?**

The printed value must be: *This the productdescription*

```
<txt field="Description" format=""> => Produces empty String
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just to use `{0}` as format?

```
<txt field="Description" format="{0}">
```

Comment: Excuse me while I hit my head the wall for some time. This answer was so freaking simple, i'm embarrassed i'd even had to ask :-/. Thanks though! I've must have had one hell of a weekend....

Comment: I had much worser moments. It happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{0}` as a format to put the first parameter of `String.Format` in its default format.

Comment: Thank you! Although i'm quite ashamed of myself now. How could I have missed this...